# Evolution not connecting to yahoo

Tags: email, evolution, yahoo

Evolution appears to not be able to connect to Yahoo email.  It prompts for the password, and keeps doing so after every attempt.  I have Thunderbird working with it so I know it can work!
I have two-factor on, but turning that off made no difference.
No error messages are giving, it just keeps prompting for the password and not working.

Comment: Does evolution work with other email services like google?

Comment: It did.  I never figured out how to get it to work with Yahoo so went back to Thunderbird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same issue, and figured out a solution.

Using your favorite browser, go to www.yahoo.com and sign into your account

Go to your inbox, and on the right hand side, click on settings.
Now on the left side, toward the bottom, it should say "switch to basic mail.  click that.
You'll be brought to a basic inbox.  Toward the top right is a drop down box.  Set that to Account info and click "Go"

Now on the left side click "Account Security"  Scroll down to the bottom, and click "App Passwords."  Generate a password, and copy it.  Paste that password into Evolution, and you can now get your emails.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd forgotten about this. I was just thinking about trying again. :-)

Comment: Thanks again!  It's working!

Comment: +1, but all I needed to do to get it working was use the "generate App Password" function

Answer (score 0):

thanks...your answer was spot on...cheers

I had this same issue, and figured out a solution.

Using your favorite browser, go to [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) and sign into your account

Go to your inbox, and on the right hand side, click on settings. Now on the left side, toward the bottom, it should say "switch to basic mail. click that.
You'll be brought to a basic inbox. Toward the top right is a drop down box. Set that to Account info and click "Go"

Now on the left side click "Account Security" Scroll down to the bottom, and click "App Passwords." Generate a password, and copy it. Paste that password into Evolution, and you can now get your emails.

Answer (score 0):

Due to changes on Yahoo side, the answers posted no longer work. Well, what to do has not changed:

- Obtain a per-app password
- Use that to log into the service you need

The part that no longer work as described is how to obtain the per-app password. You can now easily go to [your account security settings](https://login.yahoo.com/account/security?.src=yhelp)